# regular expression for removing empty lines produces wrong results

Tags: rascal

Can someone help me solve the problem I'm having with a regular expression? I have a file containing the following code:
[image: file content]

I'm using a visit to find matches and replace them so that I can remove the empty lines. The result is, however, not what I'm expecting. The code is as follows:

```
str content = readFile(location);
// Remove empty lines
content = visit (content) {
    case /^[ \t\f\v]*?$(?:\r?\n)*/sm => ""
}
```

This regular expression also removes non empty lines resulting in an output equal to:
[image: output code]

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong with the regular expression as well as the one shown below? I can't seem to figure out why it's not working.

```
str content = readFile(location);
// Remove empty lines
content = visit (content) {
    case /^\s+^/m => ""
}
```

Kind regards,

Bob

Comment: perhaps try `$` instead of `^` for the end of a line?

Comment: @JurgenVinju Thank you for your reply. However, that would beat the point since I want to include the newline so that I can remove the whole line. This works in Python. This also does not explain the problem with the regular expression used in the first code block. Any ideas?

Comment: Not yet; I always need some fiddling around to "get" a regex. Will have a go at it this afternoon perhaps 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the big issue here is that in the context of `visit`, the `^` anchor does not mean what you think it does. See this example:

```
rascal>visit ("aaa") { case /^a/ : println("yes!"); }
yes!
yes!
yes!
```

- visit matches the regex at every postfix of the string, so the ^ is relative for every postfix.
- first it starts at "aaa", then at "aa" and then at "a".

In your example visit, what will happen is that empty postfixes of lines will also match your regex, and substitute those by empty strings. I think an additional effect is that the carriage return is not eaten up eagerly.

To fix this, simply not use a visit but a `for` loop or `while`, with a `:=` match as the condition.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I got the same result and it totally didn't do what I expected it to do. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Nice. Have fun!